# ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found

Tags: python, azure, credentials, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

Im trying to allow an app service (python) to get secrets from azure keyvault without the usage of hardcoded client id/secrets, therefore I`m trying to use ManagedIdentity.

1. I have enabled system & user assigned functions in my service app
2. I have created a policy in vault where the service app is granted access to the secrets

code:

```
credentials_object = ManagedIdentityCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credentials_object)
value = client.get_secret('MYKEY').value
```

error (when app is deployed and when running locally):

> azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Running locally that is expected as there is no managed identity. It's only available in Azure. What kind of App Service are you running your app in?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux, inside a docker container

Comment: Does it work outside of python?  Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity#example-2-use-a-system-assigned-identity-to-access-azure-key-vault for example code to test.

Answer (score 16):

It's important to understand that Managed Identity feature in Azure is ONLY relevant when, in this case, the App Service is deployed. This would mean you would probably want to use `DefaultAzureCredential()` from the `Azure.Identity` library which is compatible both when running locally and for the deployed web app.

This class will run down the hierarchy of possible authentication methods and when running locally I prefer to use a service principal. Run the following in Azure CLI to create a service principal: `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name localtest-sp-rbac --skip-assignment`. You then add the service principal `localtest-sp-rbac` in the IAM for the required Azure services.

I recommend reading this article for more information and how to configure your local environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment

You can see the list of credential types that `DefaultAzureCredential()` goes through in the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that altough im using either "ManagedIdentityCredential" or "DefaultAzureCredential", I simply can not get access when the app is deployed. Therefore gaining access locally is not the issue at this point.

Comment: Also we need to assign managed identity to Azure resource (ex: Function App).

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was the issue of having multiple Managed Identities attached to my VMs. I am trying to access Azure Storage Account from AKS using ManagedIdentityCredential. When I specified the client_id of the MI as:

```
credentials_object  = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

it started to work! It's also mentioned in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-http) that we need to specify the client_id of the MI if the VM or VMSS has multiple identities attached to it.

Comment: I can confirm this works in node, thanks ! I had only one User Assigned MI for my app, but this solved the issue in my case.