# Unable to fetch secret value from Key Vault using system managed identity in C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I had enabled system assigned managed identity in azure function(Service bus topic trigger) and added the identity(Object (principal) ID
) in key vault access policy with "Get,List" permissions of secrets, keys. I added the reference of the Key Vault into Azure function Application settings and able to receive at runtime after azure function deployment.

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)`

**Code:**

```
        private async Task<string> FetchSecretValueFromKeyvault(string secretName)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"FetchSecretValueFromKeyvault: SecretName {secretName}");
            string actualSecret = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string systemAssignedClientId = GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureADManagedIdentityClientId");
                string azureKeyVaultUrl = GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureKeyVaultUrl");
                var defaultAzureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true;
                defaultAzureCredentialOptions.ManagedIdentityClientId = systemAssignedClientId;

                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(defaultAzureCredentialOptions);

                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(AzureKeyVaultUrl)), credential);
                var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                actualSecret = secret.Value.Value;
                _logger.LogInformation($"FetchSecretValueFromKeyvault:  Received secretValue for {secretName}");
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                actualSecret = string.Empty;
                _logger.LogError($"Message: {ex.Message}. \nInnerException:{ex.InnerException}. \nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}. \nInnerExceptionMessage:{ex.InnerException?.Message}.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                actualSecret = string.Empty;
                _logger.LogError($"Message: {ex.Message}. \nInnerException:{ex.InnerException}. \nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}. \nInnerExceptionMessage:{ex.InnerException?.Message}.");
            }
            return actualSecret;
        }
```

**local settings & Azure Function App Settings:**

"AzureADManagedIdentityClientId": "xxx-123-abc-xyz-567890"

"AzureKeyVaultUrl": "https://keyvaulturl.azurewebsites.net",

**Nuget package and its versions:**

Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets  -- 4.3.0

Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets -- 1.2.2

Azure.Identity  -- 1.6.1

Function Runtime Version: .NET Core V3.1

I am trying to read same secret value through code with help of same managed identity, I am getting error `ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.'` while debugging in local machine. I deployed azure function and in application insights, I am getting `No Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId. Status: 400 (Bad Request)`

I double cross checked `PrincipalId`, Its existed in both local seetings , azure function app settings and value is correct.

**what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: If you're running locally, you have to add yourself as a user in the key vault with the correct access policy. Visual Studio uses your Azure account by default for localhost.

Comment: @GHDevOps Yes I had been added to access policy.

Comment: The only difference I see between my code and yours is the use of the provider. I'm using a KeyVaultClient with an AuthenticationCallback provider (AzureServiceTokenProvider)

Comment: @GHDevOps With AzureServiceTokenProvider , is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Please check  :

1. When deployed to Azure resource that actually supports managed identity, the library automatically uses managed identities for Azure resources

***`Local machines does not support  managed identities for Azure resources`***.

2. So in local environment  Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication library uses the developer credentials.
3. For local development, `AzureServiceTokenProvider`  tries to fetch tokens  first using ***Visual Studio***, and then using ***Azure command-line interface*** (CLI), or ***Azure AD Integrated Authentication***.
4. You can try to use  `connection string` specified in the ***`AzureServicesAuthConnectionString`*** environment variable that can be passed to the AzureServiceTokenProvider .
5. You can use visual studio or azure cli method to pass to azure service authentication.
   Using ***azure cli*** , you can create service principal rbac for local testing something like

   az ad sp create-for-rbac --name local-sp --skip-assignment.

To use a `connection string` passed to the AzureServiceTokenProvider  in the AzureServicesAuthConnectionString environment variable for Local development which uses AzureCli to get token.

```
`RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli`
```

You may then have to  add the ***service principal*** `localtest-sp` in the `access control (IAM )` for the required Azure services.

[image]

6. Using the `DefaultAzureCredential` in Azure.Identity will provide some sort of similar type functionality to AzureServiceTokenProvider in AppAuthentication, where current environment can be changed.

Please check this [App Authentication client library for .NET | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication) to try for other options using secret or certificate.

Snippets from [AppAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/app-auth-migration)

> ***Using AppAuthentication library :***
>
> ```
> AzureServiceTokenProvider tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
>
> var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
>
> ...
> ```
>
> ***Using Azure.Identity library :***
>
> ```
> var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net"), new
> ```
>
> DefaultAzureCredential());
>
> ```
> var secret = client.GetSecret("secretName").Value;
> ```
>
> - ***For Access token retrival***
>
> *Using AppAuthentication library:*
>
> ```
> var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
> var accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(ResourceId);
> ```
>
> *Using Azure.Identity library:*
>
> ```
> var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
> var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
>     new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { ResourceId + "/.default" }) { }
> );
> ```

**Reference :**
[python - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367181/managedidentitycredential-authentication-unavailable-no-managed-identity-endpoi)