# How do you use System-assigned managed identity? ManagedIdentityCredential: The managed identity endpoint is indicating there's no available identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-rbac

I a resource `Azure Media Service` and an `Azure Web app` service.

What I am trying to do is turn the `web app`'s identity into a system assigned identity. I get this error `ManagedIdentityCredential: The managed identity endpoint is indicating there's no available identity. Message: undefined Status code: 400`

```js
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential({
    managedIdentityClientId: "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
});
```

- I am using the `object ID` of the `web app`.
- I then go to the resource media service (`Access Control (IAM)`) and turn on these resources: [`Media Services Account Administrator`, `Media Services Live Events Administrator`, `Media Services Operator`]

In my mind I am thinking the accessing resource (web app) Managed Identity would be the "source" and the media service would be the "target. It just gives that error.

I even tried from the web app to use the Azure role assignments `Add role assignment (preview)`.

But what's odd about that is you can't target the resource but only a subscription, resource group and some specific things.

To note, when using the user based assigned identity that works and is probably the preferable way of doing it anyway.

Comment: Kindly refer this, if this can help your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367181/managedidentitycredential-authentication-unavailable-no-managed-identity-endpoi

Comment: @VenkatV no that doesn't help at all.