# Connect Azure SQL using Azure user managed identities

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I have added UAMI as SQL AAD admin, I need to establish connection using same in pipeline to create or add users. Pipeline run on aks agent pool. Any suggestion how I can use UAMI in connection string?

I am running powershell and bash code in pipeline

Comment: Could you please provide the error if you got anything?

Comment: I am using connection string as Server=tcp:testsql.privatelink.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=cleintidMSI;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Authentication='Active Directory MSI';"      error is "ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No response  | received from the managed identity endpoint."                                                             I think i need to do AAD pod binding on aks

Comment: workload identity is the recommended way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You can try the PowerShell script below to connect to an Azure SQL server with a user-assigned managed identity:

```
$ManagedIdentityResourceId = "<UAMIresourceId>"   
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;"  
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
$connection.AccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://database.windows.net/").Token
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$query = "SELECT * FROM <tableName>"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
while ($result.Read()) {
    Write-Host $result["<column1>"], $result["<column2>"] # Replace with your column names
}
$connection.Close()
```

This script will connect to the database successfully and execute the query as shown below:

[image]

Ensure that you have assigned the required [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity?view=azuresql) to your UAMI to perform operations on the SQL database. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367181/managedidentitycredential-authentication-unavailable-no-managed-identity-endpoi).